# How to redefine the type of multiplication in Det

Tags: functions

I would like to redefine the type of multiplication that is used in Det (calculates the determinant). Instead of the standard multiplication I would like to use a custom function Fun[a,b] (which takes two elements as input and outputs one element). Is it possible to somehow redefine the multiplication operator in Det?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You probably need to reimplement it [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Levi-Civita_symbol)

Comment: Probably it would be good to explain what your ultimate goal is, and what the specific properties of the function `Fun` are. Without that information, there is a good chance that any effort to answer this could be misdirected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way that doesn't mess with an important system function:

```
Clear[a, times];
m = Array[a, {3, 3}];
TensorContract[
  Outer[times, Sequence @@ m] \[TensorProduct] LeviCivitaTensor[Length[m], List],
  Table[{i, i + Length[m]}, {i, Length[m]}]]
(*
times[a[1, 1], a[2, 2], a[3, 3]] - times[a[1, 1], a[2, 3], a[3, 2]] - 
 times[a[1, 2], a[2, 1], a[3, 3]] + times[a[1, 2], a[2, 3], a[3, 1]] +
  times[a[1, 3], a[2, 1], a[3, 2]] - times[a[1, 3], a[2, 2], a[3, 1]]
*)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly in my case, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

In principle you can redefine *safely* a native function inside [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) and given that [`Det`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Det.html) uses [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html) for symbolic matrices then

```
Block[
 {Times = f}, Det[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
 ]
```

> ```
> f[a, d] + f[-1, b, c]
> ```

As pointed out by @Kuba and @Jens there are several limitations.
A better solution would be this:

```
newDet[m_, f_] := Activate@(Block[{ms = Length[m], Times = f, a},
      Det@Table[Inactive[Part][a, i, j], {i, ms}, {j, ms}]] /. f[-1, x_, y_] -> -f[x, y] /. a -> m)
```

or

```
newDet[m_, f_] := 
 Activate@ReleaseHold@(Block[{ms = Length[m], Times = f},
      Det@Table[Inactive[Part][HoldForm[m], i, j], {i, ms}, {j, ms}]] /. f[-1, x_, y_] -> -f[x, y])
```

Now we can calculate  the new determinant with an arbitrary function `g`

```
newDet[{{2 a, b}, {c, d}}, g]
```

> ```
> g[2 a, d] - g[b, c]
> ```

More information about [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) and how is different from [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) or [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) in  [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs#answer-569)

Comment: Very nice. I was spending a stupid time making up a Det function

Comment: But it probably should be `-f[b,c]` right?

Comment: @rhermans yea, this may be easy. but what with `Block[{Times = f}, Det[{{-a, b}, {c, d}}]]` and the inner `f`?

Comment: @Kuba, I see your point, I just took the literal request of  "redefine the multiplication". Then we would need to do it  in two ways, one for the matrix operations and other for all other factors.

Comment: @rhermans Don't get me wrong :) +1ed of course. Just wanted to point those issues, maybe it matters for OP maybe not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. The first version is fully suitable for me. But why does "Block" have the HoldAll attribute? I ended up replacing "Block" with "With" in order to get my custom multiplication working.

Comment: @ftiaronsem I don't think I can explain why  and how, but I have read that `Block` is the one to use to redefine native functions. See the link to a long explanation at the end of the answer.

Comment: @Kuba I'm interested to know if you see further limitations to the current version. Cheers.

Comment: The `Block` approach doesn't work for numerical matrices, e.g., `Block[{Times = f}, Det[PauliMatrix[2]]]`

Comment: Thanks again rhermans. I looked at the links you provided, but I am not still not entirely confident in the use of Block vs With. It is probably something that  comes with experience. I decided to accept Michael's answer, since it worked better (less lines of code) for my application. But thanks a lot nonetheless!